# NUnit: how to invoke Test from another class with Parallelizable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parallel-processing, nunit

When trying to invoke a Test from a different class from where it is implemented, it does not execute the `Parallelizable` attribute, instead, it only executes the methods sequentially ( `Alltest_2()` and `Alltest_1()` ). Is there any way to invoke them so that they are executed in parallel?
Here's a code sample:

```
public class AO_Alarms_4 : AO_Alarms_3
{

    [SetUp]
    public void DefaultSetUp(){ }


    [Test]
    public void Alltest_Clases()
    {
        Alltest_2();
        Alltest_1();
    }

    [TearDown]

    public void DefaultTearDown() { }
}

[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class AO_Alarms_3 : AO_Alarms_2
{
    public WebDriverFactory driver = new WebDriverFactory(Utils.Browser);

    [SetUp]
    public void login_2()
    {
       //code
    }

    [Test]
    [Parallelizable]
    public void Alltest_2()
    {
        test_2();
    }

    public void test_2()
    {
       //code
    }

    [TearDown]

    public void teardown_2()
    {
       //code
    }
}

[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class AO_Alarms_2
{
    public WebDriverFactory driver = new WebDriverFactory(Utils.Browser);

    [SetUp]
    public void login_1()
    {
      //code
    }

    [Test]
    [Parallelizable]
    public void Alltest_1()
    {
        test1_1();
        test1_2();
    }

    [Test]
    public void test1_1()
    {
     //code
    }
    [Test]
    public void test1_2()
    {
    //code
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void teardown_1()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample is not very clear - is the inheritance important for the question?  What are the relations between the different test classes and method? Maybe you can give a more meaningful names? Omit irrelevant information (e.g. SetUp and TearDown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply call tests yourself and expect to get any of the normal NUnit behavior around tests. For example, NUnit knows what to do when **it** calls a test with `[Parallelizable]` on it - and what it does is fairly complicated. Your own call is simply calling the method you wrote.

There is nothing to stop you from calling common methods within a given test, but the tests themselves have to be invoked by NUnit.

If you can rephrase or ask another question about what you are actually trying to accomplish here, we can probably give you some advice about alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for answering! you are right, I tried to many ways in order to run tests without using Test Explorer, but there is no problems already with that because I talked with some coworkers and I don't need to call the tests as I was doing anymore. thanks for the info!